# how to get button name in mvc controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, button, model-view-controller

I have two button in mvc view (not submit)

```
    <button type="button" name="submitButton" id="s1" value="AddMore" 
    class="btn btn-success">Add More</button>
     <button type="button" name="submitButton" id="s2" value="SaveandSubmit" 
     class="btn btn-success">Save and Submit</button>
```

if anyone of them clicked, some jquery validations are there
and will submit the form explicitly

```
$("form#form1")[0].submit();
```

at controller

```
     public ActionResult AdditionStart_New(request_dtls request_dtls, string submitButton)
  {
   }
```

if the button type is "Submit" in view the button name is coming at controller but the problem is even if the jquery validation is wrong it will come for submission.

if the button type is "button" as per current code the button name is not coming in controller signature. It coming as "null". How can i get the name in controller

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to create 2 submit buttons, just intercept the submit of the second button via javascript (onclick event) and do the validation. If those don't fail, let him submit, else return false in the onclick event.

In my controller I have a custom annotation:

```
[HttpPost]
[MultipleButton(Name = "action", Argument = "Edit")]
public ActionResult Edit(EditViewModel model)
```

My buttons in my view are defined as:

```
<input type="submit" value="Toevoegen" name="action:AddItemEdit" class="btn btn-primary" />
<input type="submit" value="Opslaan" name="action:Edit" class="btn btn-success" />
```

Custom annotation being:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public class MultipleButtonAttribute : ActionNameSelectorAttribute
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Argument { get; set; }

    public override bool IsValidName(ControllerContext controllerContext, string actionName, MethodInfo methodInfo)
    {
        var isValidName = false;
        var keyValue = string.Format("{0}:{1}", Name, Argument);
        var value = controllerContext.Controller.ValueProvider.GetValue(keyValue);

        if (value != null)
        {
            controllerContext.Controller.ControllerContext.RouteData.Values[Name] = Argument;
            isValidName = true;
        }

        return isValidName;
    }
}
```

So if you want it as a parameter, or different actions in your controller, you can use the code in the MultipleButtonAttribute for both I guess. Hope this gets you somewhere.